# passing variables to a rake job not proper on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rake-task, pg

I am trying to pass a query to one one my rake jobs on heroku but the quotes are being deleted in a strange way

my rake job is

`heroku run rake namespace:job_name FILTER_QUERY="'data like \"%test%\"'" -a heroku_project_name`

the error that I am getting is

> PG::UndefinedColumnERROR: column "%test%" does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...at >  (data like "%test%")

on my local this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are actually making it through just fine, but Postgres treats everything in double-quotes as an identifier (in this case, a column name). You need to use single-quotes in `'%test%'` and reorganize the rest from there.

From [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html):

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an identifier